Transfer Data from Local Storage to new page in Project in ASP.NET
this is my script that transfer some data from Local Storage to User panel to AddToCart Method:

        $(document).ready(function () {
            // Click handler for both cart-link and user-panel-link
            $("#cart-link, #isAuthenticated").click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                var isAuthenticated = $('#isAuthenticated').val() === 'true';

                if (isAuthenticated) {
                    var chefFoodIdsStored = localStorage.getItem('chefFoodIds');
                    var chefFoodIdsArray = chefFoodIdsStored ? JSON.parse(chefFoodIdsStored) : [];

                    if (chefFoodIdsArray.length > 0) {
                        var chefFoodIdsString = chefFoodIdsArray.map(id => `chefFoodIds=${id}`).join('&');
                        var addToCartUrl = `/UserPanel/AddToCart?${chefFoodIdsString}`;

                        window.location.href = addToCartUrl;
                        localStorage.removeItem('chefFoodIds');
                        updateCartCounter(); // به روزرسانی تعداد غذاهای سبد خرید
                    } else {
                        window.location.href = '/UserPanel/AddToCart';
                    }
                } else {
                    var returnUrl = $('#hidden-returnUrl').val() || '/UserPanel/AddToCart';
                    $('#Login').modal('show');
                    $('#Login').find('.modal-content').load('/Account/Login', function () {
                        var chefFoodIdsStored = localStorage.getItem('chefFoodIds');
                        var chefFoodIdsArray = chefFoodIdsStored ? JSON.parse(chefFoodIdsStored) : [];
                        $('#hidden-chefFoodIds').val(chefFoodIdsArray.join(','));
                        $('#hidden-returnUrl').val(returnUrl);
                    });
                }
            });

            function updateCartCounter() {
                var chefFoodIdsStored = localStorage.getItem('chefFoodIds');
                var chefFoodIdsArray = chefFoodIdsStored ? JSON.parse(chefFoodIdsStored) : [];
                var cartCounter = chefFoodIdsArray.length;

                $('.cart-counter').text(cartCounter);
            }
        });

but when user goes to cart, if for example click on the other tab in panel , the data in local storage was delete
how can I save this data when I want to go to other tab or page?
this is my method:

        [HttpGet("/UserPanel/AddToCart")]
        public async  Task<IActionResult> AddToCart(List<int> chefFoodIds)
        {

            if (chefFoodIds == null || !chefFoodIds.Any())
            {
                 
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }

          
            var cartItems = await _orderService.GetCartItemForShow(chefFoodIds);
            ViewData["CartItemCount"] = cartItems.Sum(item => item.Quantity);


            return View(cartItems);
        }

